# OpenCV for Android: Bitmap is null (bmp == null)

Tags: android, opencv, android-bitmap

I am trying to load an image into a bitmap so I can make some processing on tha cameraframe, but I keep getting bmp == null when I try to use the static image.
Here is my code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path,"/myopencv/myimage.bmp");
    if (file.exists()) {
        objectbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        object = new Mat();
        Log.e("Get frame","next line generates the error: bmp == null");
        Utils.bitmapToMat(objectbmp, object);
       }
  }
```

So I used Eclipse to open my DDMS towards my physical device. I created a new folder myopencv inside /storage/sdcard0/. Then I placed the myimage.bmp file there using Eclipses tool (Push a file onto the device).
So the file clearly exists.
Also I test for it, to see if the file exists, and it seems to exist.
So why is it null?
How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

If your file really exists,I only guess `objectbmp` is invalid.[Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#bitmapToMat(Bitmap,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) say:

> bmp - is a valid input Bitmap object of the type 'ARGB_8888' or
>   'RGB_565'.

Why you do not use [Highgui.imread](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread(java.lang.String)) ? Docs say:

> Loads an image from a file.
>
> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns
>   it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper
>   permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an
>   empty matrix (Mat.data==NULL). Currently, the following file formats
>   are supported:
>
> Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported) JPEG files - *.jpeg,
>   *.jpg, *.jpe (see the *Notes* section) JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the *Notes* section) Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the
>   *Notes* section) Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm (always supported) Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported) TIFF files -
>   *.tiff, *.tif (see the *Notes* section)